# Starting with laravel on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel

I'm trying laravel as a PHP framework, I have already extracted the laravel zip into `~/opt/xampp/htdocs/laravel` but when I go to `localhost/laravel` or `localhost/laravel` I get a 403 error message saying:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

I read somewhere that I need to edit the `storage` folder inside of laravel so it can be readable and writable so I `chmod -R 766 laravel/storage` but still no luck, I'm doing this from Ubuntu 12.04 have anyone encountered this ?

**EDIT** 
I have `chmod -R 0+w laravel/storage` and now when i go to `localhost/laravel` i get an index of some files in there, but when i go to `localhost/laravel/public/` still get the 403 error, instead of the expected result

**EDIT 2** 
I have set `chmod -R 765 laravel/public` and now when i get to `localhost/laravel/public` i get this message which leads me to believe i'm getting closer:

> Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/learning-laravel/laravel/laravel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/learning-laravel/public/index.php on line 34
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/learning-laravel/laravel/laravel.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/learning-laravel/public/index.php on line 34

Comment: Have you tried giving appropriate rights to `~/opt/xampp/htdocs/laravel`?

Comment: @OzairKafray yeah, still no luck

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Final Update**
I finally solved it, what happened was that the `laravel` folder was read protected, what i had to do was to set `chmod 755 -R laravel` and then `chmod -R o+w storage` and voila i had laravel up and running, thanks to everybody that contributed.

Comment: Just for the right syntax: You need to write `chmod -R 755 laravel` ;-)

Comment: I would rather use the solution from @Sirlate because by your solution you are basically doing  chmod 757 -R storage which means that anybody can read and write to the storage folder where are sessions, logs.. also written. So basically I see it as security risk. So even your sister can read that folder if she has guest account on your computer.

Answer (score 17):

for just getting start with laravel, I just do these following steps:

```
sudo chmod -R 770 /your/path/to/laravel/folder/
```

then add www-data group to your laravel

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /your/path/to/laravel/folder/
```

Comment: Thanks, this made deploying from Github/Bitbucket a whole lot smoother.

Answer (score 5):

Your on the right track, after install of laravel you need to ensure the storage directory has the correct permissions:

```
sudo chmod o+w storage
```

Then make sure you are serving your public folder and not your laravel folder in apaches document root

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/JonSnow/Sites/MySite/public
    ServerName mysite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Both requirements are [covered here](http://laravel.com/docs/install)

Comment: do i really need to add the virtualhost into my apache configuration ?

Comment: @IsaacGonzalez -you don't need to add a virtual host no. From the looks of it, it seems as if your permissions are all jacked up. Trash what you've done so far, download laravel again, extract to ~/opt/xampp/htdocs/laravel then run one permissions change to the storage directory

Comment: I found it necessary to change permissions recursively on the storage directory.  Ex:  `sudo chmod -R o+w storage`

Answer (score 0):

On the Laravel forum, Kaspien gave this usefull answers:

> You do have to chmod 777, but only on the storage/views folder to use blade, which happens to be the view engine the default Laravel view uses. I usually chmod 777 all storage/* directories on a fresh install of Laravel before I start a project, since they have to be writable for views, sessions, etc.

From the thread: http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=1552

Answer (score -1):

In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ /public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This assumes that /laravel/laravel.php is actually readable. This won't solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score -3):

Change permission to the storage and bootstrap folders like so

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./storage ./bootstrap
```

Comment: never set a directory to `777`!