# installing laravel problems

Tags: php, laravel

hello I want to install laravel on my local macbook and i did do the following.. I installed laravel with composer. I installed php5-mcrypt with macports and I think its loaded ( seeing the php.ini file ) [image: phpini]
After this when i go to where the laravel is installed /localhost/~user/laraveldir/

instead of getting the index page I just see all the files the public folder I can't see tho.. and that is the part where index.php is located. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

**Additional
I have found out that I have 2 php "servers" on my macbook the one that is in 
/opt/local/bin/php and this is version 5.3.15 but the ini file says its 5.4.13 and this one is loaded from /usr/local/php5/bin/php Can I just remove one and keep the other one or does that not matter?

Comment: What happens when you go to /localhost/~user/laraveldir/index.php directly? If that works, you have to set up your web server to use index.php as the default index page: `DirectoryIndex index.php`.

Comment: i get a The requested URL /~user/beta/index.php was not found on this server.and when trying to the public You don't have permission to access /~user/beta/public/index.php on this server. while the rights are correct .. 755 ( even tried on 777 )

Comment: You'll have to check your error logs. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981621/starting-with-laravel-on-ubuntu and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345174/cant-make-laravel-4-to-work-on-localhost

Comment: in my logs i get Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /Users/user/Sites/beta/public/, referer: http://localhost/~user/ i fixed this with Options FollowSymLinks but now i get that there is no index.php while there definitly is

Comment: i just found out when i go to index.php myself it now works! but still have to do some modifications i guess to make this work properly