# Laravel - Recommended server permissions Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, permissions

I have deployed successfully a Laravel website, although to modify the files over SMB share I had to modify the entire `/var/www` folder permissions to `777`.

Can that cause a security issue? What should be correct permissions?

Many thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981621/starting-with-laravel-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the entire folder a `755` permission so all files can be read by the server. The `app/storage` folder should have `777` to make sure it is writable.