# Deploying Laravel 5 application on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I just deployed my laravel 5 app on heroku, but when I try to access it on

http://myapp.herokuapp.com/public/

it shows me this error **Whoops, looks like something went wrong.** error.

This is my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=random_string

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=benchmarks
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=something

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

what should I do to, for my app to show proper error message?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to update the permissions on some folders.

From Laravel documentation (and experience setting up many Laravel installs):

> **Permissions**
>
> Laravel may require one set of permissions to be configured: folders
>   within storage and vendor require write access by the web server.

Try and see if `chmod -R 775 app/storage/` works.

Also, in the storage folder, it should have an error log organized daily you can parse through to see what went wrong.

http://crynobone.com/posts/9/customizing-the-default-error-page-on-laravel-5.1),

Comment: in my storage folder there is no log file

Comment: It's most likely because of the chmod issue. The server cannot write a log file to view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981621/starting-with-laravel-on-ubuntu