# Laravel - Basic routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I have encounter some problems when changing the default page of the project.

I have installed Laravel and try to change the route setting

> Route::get("/", function(){return view("welcome");})

to

> Route::get("/", function(){return view("home");})

. I have added a simple php page home.blade.php in Resources/views but it couldn't display "home" page.

I have also tried to use Controller approach by adding a HomeController and there is a function called "showHomePage" which will returns view("home") but still no luck.

Are there any setting / configuration is needed ? Thank you

Comment: Can you show error?

Comment: Http 500 error only. No Laravel Error

Comment: Ok, you should chmod 777 folder storage and chmod 775 vendor. And try again

Comment: Ok, I will try it but the default welcome page works fine. Just the new added page not working.

Comment: Because, when you add new file view, laravel render file view in storage/framework/views. And you should chmod permission folder storage, it will work

Comment: You can see more : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981621/starting-with-laravel-on-ubuntu

Comment: Got it. I will try it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for mydo47 suggestion. chmod 777 folder storage and chmod 775 vendor (Apply to all sub-folder recursively) solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

you need to clear the compiled view files after changing the template or any view code. ( no need to use command serve)

```
php artisan view:clear
```

or delete all files in storage/framework/views

or you should chmod 777 folder storage and chmod 775 vendor.