# Get error when in staging server, but not in local

Tags: php, laravel, local, staging

im getting this error when i submit the form

> ErrorException in AuthentificationController.php line 255:
>   Undefined variable: user

This is the AuthentificationController.php line 255

> \Session::put('shipping', $totalShipping);

im confused because this error only appearing when in staging server, when i try launch in local with same branch its not error.
i had pull branch too.

can someone help me?
im using laravel 5.1

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Client;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\City;
use App\Models\InfoPengiriman;
use App\Models\Location;
use App\Models\ProductRegion;
use App\Models\Province;
use App\Models\RegionCategory;
use App\Models\SettingEmail;
use App\Models\Shipping;
use App\Models\ShippingAdress;
use App\Models\ShippingTransportation;
use App\Models\Transaction;
use App\Models\TransactionDetail;
use App\Models\User;
use Cart;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Mail;
use Sentinel;
use Session;
use Validator;
class AuthentificationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $data['provinces'] = Province::orderBy('name','ASC')->get();
        if( Session::get('province_id')) {
          $data['cities'] = [null=>'- silakan pilih wilayah -'] + City::where( ['province_id'=> Session::get('province_id')])->lists('name', 'id')->all();
        } else {
          $data['cities'] = [null=>'- silakan pilih wilayah -'];
        }
        if(\Sentinel::check()) {
          $data['user'] = User::find(\Sentinel::getUser()->id);
        }
        $region = RegionCategory::find(session('id_wilayah'));
        $data['city'] = RegionCategory::find(session('id_wilayah'));
        return view('client.authentification.create',$data);
    }
     /**
     * Generate New Password
     *
     */
    private function generatePassword($length = 6)
    {
        $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
        $count = mb_strlen($chars);
        for ($i = 0, $result = ''; $i < $length; $i++) {
          $index = rand(0, $count - 1);
          $result .= mb_substr($chars, $index, 1);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $regType = session('regType');
      $incurance = 0;
      if($regType == 'children') {
        $regId = session('id_wilayah');
        $qReg = RegionCategory::find($regId);
        $incurance = $qReg->percentage_incurance ? $qReg->percentage_incurance : 0;
      }
      if(Sentinel::check()){
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), ['first_name_dlv' => 'required']);
      }else{
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), ['first_name' => 'required', 'email' => 'required' ]);
      }
      if($validation->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->messages())->with('error', 'Please input the correct data');
      } else {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
          \Session::put('location', $request->city_dlv);
          $genrate = substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) , 0, 8);
          \Session::put('genrate',$genrate);
          $cityId   = $request->city_dlv;
          $regionId = session('id_wilayah');
          $locationId = Location::where('city_id', $cityId)->first()->id;
          $shipping   = RegionCategory::find($regionId)
                                ->shipping()
                                ->where('location_id', $locationId)
                                ->first();
          if(count($shipping)) {
            $shippingId = $shipping->id;
            \Session::put('shippingId', $shippingId);
          }
          if(Sentinel::check()){
            ShippingAdress::create([
                'first_name'  => $request->first_name_dlv,
                'last_name'   => $request->last_name_dlv,
                'address'     => $request->address_dlv,
                'province_id' => $request->province_dlv,
                'city_id'     => $request->city_dlv,
                'phone'       => $request->phone_dlv,
                'user_id'     => Sentinel::check()->id,
                'kode'        => $genrate
            ]);
            \Session::put('user_id', Sentinel::check()->id);
          }else{
            $users = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
            if($users) {
              $user = User::find($users->id);
              $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
              $user->last_name  = $request->last_name;
              $user->city_id    = $request->city_id;
              $user->address    = $request->address;
              $user->phone      = $request->phone;
              $user->save();
              ShippingAdress::create([
                  'first_name'  => $request->first_name_dlv,
                  'last_name'   => $request->last_name_dlv,
                  'address'     => $request->address_dlv,
                  'province_id' => $request->province_dlv,
                  'city_id'     => $request->city_dlv,
                  'phone'       => $request->phone_dlv,
                  'user_id'     => $user->id,
                  'kode'        => $genrate
              ]);
              \Session::put('user_id', $user->id);
            }else{
              $user = User::create([
                  'email'    => $request->email,
                  'password' => $this->generatePassword(),
                  //     'username' => str_replace(' ', '_', $request->first_name),
                  'first_name' => $request->first_name,
                  'last_name'  => $request->last_name,
                  'city_id'    => $request->city_id,
                  'address'    => $request->address,
                  'phone'      => $request->phone,
              ]);
              ShippingAdress::create([
                  'first_name'  => $request->first_name_dlv,
                  'last_name'   => $request->last_name_dlv,
                  'address'     => $request->address_dlv,
                  'province_id' => $request->province_dlv,
                  'city_id'     => $request->city_dlv,
                  'phone'       => $request->phone_dlv,
                  'user_id'     => $user->id,
                  'kode'        => $genrate
              ]);
              \Session::put('user_id', $user->id);
            }
          }
          /* Save Transaction */
          $shipping = Shipping::where('region_category_id',session('location'))
                                ->where('type',session('type_komoditi'))->first();
          if($shipping)
          {
            $shippingPrice = $shipping->price;
          } else {
            $default = Shipping::where('region_category_id' ,0)->first();
            $shippingPrice = 75000;
          }
          if($regType == 'children') {
              $weight = session('totalWeight');
              $multipleWeight = $request->multiple_weight ? $request->multiple_weight : 0;
              $calc = $weight / $multipleWeight;
              if(! $calc) {
                $resultMultipleWeight = 0;
              }
              if(strpos($calc, '.')) {
                $splitNumber = explode('.', $calc);
                if($splitNumber[1] < 999) {
                    $numb = 1;
                    $total = $splitNumber[0] + $numb;
                    $resultMultipleWeight = $total;
                }
              } else {
                $resultMultipleWeight = $calc;
              }
              $shippingPrice = $request->shipping_price ?: $shippingPrice;
              $totalShipping = $resultMultipleWeight * $shippingPrice;
              $incurance = $request->incurance ?: $incurance;
          } else {
              $totalShipping = $shippingPrice;
          }
          $paycode = mt_rand(100,999);
          // Rekap Harga
          $totalPrice = Cart::total();
          $incurancePrice = $totalPrice / 100 * $incurance;
          $grandTotalPrice = $totalPrice + $incurancePrice + $totalShipping + $paycode;
          $grandTotalPriceWithoutPaycode = $totalPrice + $incurancePrice + $totalShipping;
          \Session::put('price', $totalPrice);
          \Session::put('totalPrice', $grandTotalPriceWithoutPaycode);
          \Session::put('grandTotalPrice', $grandTotalPrice);
          \Session::put('grandTotalPriceWithoutPaycode', $grandTotalPriceWithoutPaycode);
          \Session::put('shipping', $totalShipping);
          //\Session::put('paycode', $paycode);
          \Session::put('incurance', $incurance);
          \Session::put('incurancePrice', $incurancePrice);
          if($transportId = $request->input('shipping_transportation_id')) {
              $qTransportation = ShippingTransportation::find($transportId);
              $transportName = $qTransportation->name;
              \Session::put('transportName', $transportName);
          }
          $user  = User::find(session('user_id'));
          $store = Transaction::create([
              'kode'            => session('genrate'),
              'customer_id'     => session('user_id'),
              'type_komoditi'   => session('type_komoditi'),
              'type_payment'    => 0,
              'location'        => session('location'),
              'status_payment'  => 1,
              'status_delivery' => 1,
              'paycode'   => $paycode,
              'incurance' => $incurance,
              'shipping_transportation_id' => $request->shipping_transportation_id ?: 0,
              'shipping_price' => $totalShipping ?: 0,
          ]);
          $carts = Cart::content();
          foreach ($carts as $value) {
            TransactionDetail::create([
                'transaction_id' => $store->id,
                'qty'            => $value->qty,
                'product_id'     => $value->options->product_id,
                'kemasan'        => $value->options->kemasan,
                'price'          => $value->price,
            ]);
            $region = ProductRegion::find($value->options->product_region_id);
            $region->stock = $region->stock - $value->qty;
            $region->save();
          }
          \Session::put('kode', $store->kode);
          \Session::put('transId', $store->id);
          DB::commit();
          return Redirect::route('client.payment.create')->with('success','Otentifikasi Berhasil Di Simpan');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          DB::rollback();
          return Redirect::route('client.authentification.create')->with('errors','Otentifikasi Gagal Di Simpan');
        }
         // return Redirect::route('client.payment.create');
      }
    }
  }
```

i try to change "return Redirect::route('client.payment.create')->with('success','Otentifikasi Berhasil Di Simpan');" into return 'string';
but the result is still the same :(

Comment: show your AuthentificationController.php code..

Comment: Make sure you have permissions on the storage folder.

Comment: @pritesh i had attach authentificationcontroller above, thankyou

Comment: @Troyer how to make that? sorry im still newbie :(

Comment: @FaisalHilmi In case you use Ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981621/starting-with-laravel-on-ubuntu